# Stochastic matrix - semisimple eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How can we prove that eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ is *semisimple* for any arbitrary stochastic matrix?
$$\lambda \:\text{semisimple}\iff (algebraic\, multiplicity  \,\lambda = geometric \,multiplicity\, \lambda)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT. This old proof proves nothing. Sorry for the OP.

Let $A$ be a stochastic matrix. There exists a permutation matrix $P$ s.t.
                $PAP^{-1} = \left( \begin{smallmatrix} B_1 & * & * & \cdots & * \\ 0 & B_2 & * & \cdots & * \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & * \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & B_h \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ where the $B_i$'s are either irreducible or zero.  $spectrum(A)=\{sp(B_1),\cdots,{s}p(B_h)\}$. If $1\in{s}p(B_i)$ then $B_i$ is irreducible and therefore $1$ is a SIMPLE eigenvalue of $B_i$.

Unfortunately, we can only conclude that the number of indices $i$ s.t. $1\in sp(B_i)$ is equal to  the algebraic multiplicity of $1$.

A correct proof is as follows.

$\textbf{Proposition.}$ If $A$ is stochastic, then all the eigenvalues of $A$ with modulus $1$ are semi simple.

$\textbf{Proof.}$ For every $k$, $A^k$ is stochastic; then $||A^k||_{\infty}=1$ and the sequence $(A^k)_k$ is bounded. Then each Jordan block of $A$ associated to an eigenvalue of modulus $1$ is $1\times 1$.  $\square$

Comment: @ thanasissdr , yes the $B_i$'s are square and yes the permutation $P$ always exists. About your proposed matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\1/2&0&1/2\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$, one has $A^5>0$ ; then $A$ is primitive and consequently irreducible.

Comment: Yeap, I realized that my $A$ was already irreducible, that's why I deleted it. You probably use Perron - Frobenius theorem for non - negative, irreducible matrices (justifying $\rho(B_i)=1$ is simple, when $1$ belongs to $sp(B_i)$).