# Stochastic matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

I am trying to prove that eigen values of row stochastic matrix/ column stochastic matrix/ doubly stochastic matrix need not be necessarily simple. Is there any mathematical proof?

Comment: To show that a stochastic matrix need not have distinct eigenvalues, you just need to give an example of a stochastic matrix where at least one eigenvalue is repeated.

Comment: Try to work out what happens in the case when the underlying graph has two connected components. I think this might give you what you want.

Comment: You can consider as a (counter) example the identity matrix. The eigenvalue $\lambda  = 1$ is semi - simple.

Comment: Also, you may find [this link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044491/stochastic-matrix-semisimple-eigenvalue) quite useful.